# TypeError: 'str' object is not callable Error When I don't use any strings, only integers

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have been struggling with an issue where I am unable to run this block of code without a TypeError:

```
def subtract(num1, num2):
    return num1 - num2


n1 = int(input("What is your first number?"))
n2 = int(input("What is your second number?"))

subtract(n1, n2)
```

I try to pass two numbers into the subtract funtion and subtract them, but it gives an error. It seems like the code is so simple that there can not possibly be an error, but for some reason it is giving this error. I tried to go on other stack overflow pages with the same issue, but none of them solve my exact problem. Please help, Thank you!

Comment: You have previously assigned a string value to `int` or `input`, perhaps.  Restarting your Python interpreter would fix this.

Comment: ~Gary I tried running this in pycharm it works, where did you run it ?

Comment: The issue was i declared input as a variable before, thank you! I ran it in kaggle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works fine for me here: https://repl.it/@LukeStorry/63023113

How are you trying to run it? Maybe you have set `int` or `input` (used as functions here) to a string value previously, and have overwritten the functions, so closing and restarting your session or IDE could help.